# Why are my matlab plots filled in?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to do some simulations for gasses using Matlab and I wish to plot the predicted data taken from Matrix M. This data should appear as single lines but instead it looks like it is being plotted and filled between two values. Where am I going wrong?
Thanks in advance

```
%Basic One Dimensional Simulation

%Set Parameters
Y = 1.32;   %spec heat ratio
po = 103200; %pressure at outlet
pi = 300000; %pressure at inlet
dx = 0.3; %length of control volume
cbar = 340.29; %average speed of sound, m/s
Fr = 4; %Frequency of wave
Cd = 0.7; %Discharge coefficient
Tu = 1800; %Rough temperature of LNG combustion
Am = 1; %amplitude of wave
A = 1; %Cross sectional area of exhaust chamber
Ao = 0.4; %Cross sectional area of exhaust exit
Ai = 0.3; %Cross sectional area of exhaust inlet

%Define simulation setting time constants
Ts = 0.0001;  %Sampling interval, sec
T = 1;      %simulation time, sec
mt = T/Ts;   %Number of iterations


%Initial values
%Mass flow rates
Mg = 0.0110352; %Mass flow rate of gas
Ma = 0.189189; %Mass flow rate of air
Mi = Mg + Ma; %Total Mass flow rate at inlet
M4 = Mi;
M3 = M4;
M2 = M3;
M1 = M2;

p1 = po; %Pressure, Pa
p2 = p1;
p3 = p2;
p4 = p3;

%Simulation    
M = zeros(mt);
N = zeros(mt);
for j = 0:1:mt
    t=j*Ts;

Mi = Mg + Ma; %Mass flow rate based on input flow rates
a = (Ma/0.172);
Rexhaust = (84373 + 70841*a)/(290.67 + 210.67*a);

%Predicting Mass Flow Rate at exit
Cm1 = (((2*Y)/(Rexhaust*(Y-1)))*(((po/p1)^(2/Y))*((po/p1)^((Y+1)/Y))))^(1/2);
Cm2 = ((2/(Y+1))^(1/(Y-1)))*(2*Y/Rexhaust*(Y+1))^(1/2);

Pratio = (2/(Y+1))^(Y/(Y-1));

if po/p1 > Pratio;
Mo = Cd*Cm1*Ao*p1/(Tu)^(1/2);
else
Mo = Cd*Cm2*Ao*p1/(Tu)^(1/2);
end

%Position 1
dpdt1 = ((Rexhaust*Tu)/(dx*A))*(Mo-M1);
drhodt1 = dpdt1/(Rexhaust*Tu);
p1 = dpdt1*Ts;
M1 = (dpdt1*A*dx)/(Rexhaust*Tu);


%Position 2
dpdt2 = ((Rexhaust*Tu)/(dx*A))*(M1-M2);
drhodt2 = dpdt2/(Rexhaust*Tu);
p2 = dpdt2*Ts;
M2 = (dpdt2*A*dx)/(Rexhaust*Tu);


%Position 3
dpdt3 = ((Rexhaust*Tu)/(dx*A))*(M2-M3);
drhodt3 = dpdt3/(Rexhaust*Tu);
p3 = dpdt3*Ts;
M3 = (dpdt3*A*dx)/(Rexhaust*Tu);


%Position 4
%Predicting Mass Flow Rate at inlet
Cm1 = (((2*Y)/(Rexhaust*(Y-1)))*(((p4/pi)^(2/Y))*((p4/pi)^((Y+1)/Y))))^(1/2);
Cm2 = ((2/(Y+1))^(1/(Y-1)))*(2*Y/Rexhaust*(Y+1))^(1/2);

Pratio = (2/(Y+1))^(Y/(Y-1));

if p4/pi > Pratio;
M4 = Cd*Cm1*Ai*pi/(Tu)^(1/2);
else
M4 = Cd*Cm2*Ai*pi/(Tu)^(1/2);
end
dpdt4 = ((Rexhaust*Tu)/(dx*A))*(M3-M4);
drhodt4 = dpdt4/(Rexhaust*Tu);
p4 = dpdt4*Ts;
M4 = (dpdt4*A*dx)/(Rexhaust*Tu);    


%Save current values to Matrix M
d = [t Mo M1 M2 M3 M4 Mi dpdt1 dpdt2 dpdt3 dpdt4 drhodt1 drhodt2 drhodt3 drhodt4];
for i = 1:1:15
    M(j+1,i) = d(i);
end

%Save current p  to Matrix N
e = [t po p1 p2 p3 p4];               
for k=1:1:6
   N(j+1,k) = e(k);
end


end


%FIGURES
F1 = figure(1);
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 2), 'y'); %outlet
hold on
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 3), 'g'); %position 1
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 4), 'r'); %position 2
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 5), 'b'); %position 3
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 6), 'm'); %position 4
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 7), 'c'); %inlet
grid on
hold off
legend('outlet','M1','M2','M3','M4','Mi');
title('MASS FLOW RATES');

subplot(3,1,2);
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 8), 'g'); %position 1
hold on
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 9), 'r'); %position 2
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 10), 'b'); %position 3
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 11), 'm'); %position 4
grid on
hold off
legend('dpdt1','dpdt2','dpdt3','dpdt4');
title('RATE OF CHANGE OF PRESSURES');

subplot(3,1,3);
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 12), 'g'); %position 1
hold on
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 13), 'r'); %position 2
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 14), 'b'); %position 3
plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 15), 'm'); %position 4
grid on
hold off
legend('drhodt1','drhodt2','drhodt3','drhodt4');
title('RATE OF CHANGE OF DENSITIES');


F2 = figure(2);
plot(N(:, 1), N(:, 2), 'g');
hold on
plot(N(:, 1), N(:, 2), 'r');
plot(N(:, 1), N(:, 2), 'b');
plot(N(:, 1), N(:, 2), 'm');
hold off`enter code here`
legend('p1','p2','p3','p4');
title('PRESSURES');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filled area is due to the nature of the data (i.e. high frequency component). The following plot shows the same data, `plot(M(:, 1), M(:, 6), 'm');`, but on a different scale (zoom on the right).

[image]

If you take `M(1:2:end, 1)` and  `M(2:2:end, 1)`, you will have the local extremums.

Comment: Thank you! Better drop the frequency a bit!